# How can I get the discussions that a user has contributed to?

Tags: discussion-board

If a user has posted to various discussions across a SharePoint web application, how can I get the posts they have made in order to populate a web part (using C#)? Also is it possible to get topics most viewed or replied to? Wanting to do a home page would be something like this:

```
My Topics                   Popular Topics
----------------------------------------------------------
Topic        Replies        Topic                  Replies
=====        =======        =====                  =======
My Topic     4              Something interesting  120
My Topic 2   0              Not as interesting     40
```

Need to know the API's to use more than the actual HTML/CSS code to write.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just run a query with SP.list. I haven't really done any work with discussions in 2010, but my understanding is that it's fairly unchanged from 2007. There should be a post count (or similar) column. I have done this in 2007 with a DVWP. You can use the U2U CAML Query tool to determine what the column name is.

In short, I don't think you should have to do anything complex (nothing outside of a straight query anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use an [SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx) to query the site collection, looking for messages or discussions that were posted by the user. I think that Discussions have a [content type beginning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452896.aspx) 0x012002, replies have the type beginning 0x0107

Similarly, I'd use an SPSiteDataQuery to get *just* Discussions, and order the results - but I'm not sure what field to order by, as I'm not sure what would hold the 'count' of the replies.